# Trigger a custom event on a dynamic element

Tags: jquery

I created a custom login.validate event and binded it to .question dynamic element.
I am not able to trigger the new event using trigger method (). here is the JS fiddle  and script http://jsfiddle.net/PzSYM/400/

```
<h2></h2>
<button>generate new element</button>
<p class="generateEvent">Trigger event validate</p>


$("button").click(function() {
    $("h2").html("<p class='test'>click me</p>")
});


$('p.test').bind('validate', function(){

    alert('This is working');
})

$('h2').on('login.validate', 'p.test', function(){
    console.log('Good now the validate event need to be trigered');
});

$('.generateEvent').click(function(){
    $('p.test').trigger('login.validate');

});
```

How do I trigger the custom event in the dynamic elements?

Comment: It works, Whats the issue?

Comment: the console does not trigger  console.log('Good now the validate event need to be trigered');  ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegates. Here is working sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/PzSYM/414/

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("h2").html("<p class='test'>click me</p>")
});


$(document).on('validate', 'p.test', function () {
    alert('This is working');
})

$('h2').on('login.validate', 'p.test', function () {
    console.log('Good now the validate event need to be trigered');
});

$('.generateEvent').on('click', function () {
    $('p.test').trigger('validate');
});
```